# Library for video conversion from one format to another format

Tags: video-conversion, format-conversion, media-library

Are there any libraries in Ubuntu for converting video files into another format??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact there are lots. The most common used is FFmpeg-`libav`. VLC utilises this library.